# Django 1.5: user and additional info

Tags: django

I have an authentication system based on django auth, but I have to add information to users.
What is the best way to do that in django 1.5? (In 1.4 i was using a profile linked with onetoone to user, but now?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Django 1.5 has [extendable User models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). Basically, you can extend an abstract base user model, add your fields and anything and use it from there.

The base model only has the basics for authentication – the password field and a field for the time of the last login. You even have to create your own username field. If you're comfortable with something like current Django User model (with username, first name, last name, etc.), it also exists as `AbstractUser` and you can extend it instead of `AbstractBaseUser` and add your own fields.

Comment: Yeah i read that on the doc. But i don't want to implement an AbstractBaseUser because what i need is already in User. I have only to add things. So, how to code that?

Comment: User is basically the same as AbstractUser, but with a SWAPPABLE atribute (whatever it is for) https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L457 . So just make your own model inherit from AbstractUser.

Comment: I inherited, but on syncdb i got the follwing errors: CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
account.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
account.user: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.

Comment: Have you followed all the required steps, like setting the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting and changing your relations to point to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` rather than the django auth User model?

Answer (score 0):

In django 1.5 you should create a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user). User profiles are now deprecated.

Comment: Where does it say that extending the user model with a "profile" is deprecated?   The 'development' django docs and 1.7 docs both present this as the first solution, and AUTH_USER_MODEL comes wiht some pretty heavy warnings and implications...

Comment: `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` is [deprecated as of django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#auth-profile-module).