# Django 1.5 + User model relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django 1.5+ allows us to add custom fields to a User. I want to use this fact, but I don't necessarily know what is good practice. Here is a situation I am confused on how to handle the models.

Given the option to add fields to `User`, if a project only has one type of `User`, lets say a `Student` model, can I simply add student-specific fields to `User`? I am new to Django, but I believe the alternative would be to set up general `User` settings, and create a `Student` model, and a one-to-one unique field in it call user.

Should you ever expand a Django `User`'s fields to mimic that of a model, even if the project is guaranteed only to have one type of user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only have one type of user and are using Django 1.5+, I would recommend taking advantage of the new AbstractUser. [Extending Django's default user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user)

As an example where you want to add date of birth and favorite color:

```
#myusers/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    dob = models.DateField()
    favorite_color = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='Blue')
```

If you need more flexibility you can extend the AbstractBaseUser instead of AbstractUser, but for most basic cases you should only need AbstractUser.

Also note that in either case, you'll need to [reference your user model by using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Using out example above and assuming the app it was defined in is called `myusers`:

```
#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myusers.MyUser'
```

The method you mention of creating a Student model with a one-to-one field to the User model still works, but is not as clean (there are still cases where it makes sense if you have multiple kinds of users).

I don't normally like to reference books in answers, but I found that *[Two Scoops of Django's](https://django.2scoops.org/)*, Chapter 16 on the User model gave a much clearer explanation of where the different options are appropriate than the current version of the online Django docs.  The book is overall a very useful intro to Django and was written based on 1.5.  You'd have to buy the book or find someone who has it, though... (FYI: I don't get any money recommending this).

You could also take a look at this SO question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14104748/307293

Comment: What is not clean about it?

Comment: It creates an extra table in the database.  If you're referencing things like first name and last name frequently along with some of your custom information that requires an extra JOIN every time.

Comment: Jacinda - coincidentally I had purchased the book earlier today! I haven't gotten there yet, but looking at that reference, they give three good options: linking back from a related model, subclass AbstractUser, or subclass AbstractBaseClassUser. Unfortunately I am using a third party app that I want to subclass, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hmm...without knowing the specific app it's difficult to give any reasonable advice.  Maybe a separate SO question unless it's a proprietary app?

Comment: [django-userena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/models.py), if you feel answering would be out of scope of a comment I can make a new SO question. Basically I just want to subclass  UserenaBaseProfile, from the link above

Comment: Ah, I see. It looks like that project is still dependent on AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE. I thin you could create a custom user model as outlined above and just create a profile model that inherits from UserenaBaseProfile that has a one-to-one relationship with your user model (using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) but doesn't add any extra fields there. I think you'll have to do this with 1.5 because AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE has been deprecated.  You may want to send a question to the userena developers to see what they recommend as I imagine this might be changing some of their code.

Comment: There may also be another option I missed since I didn't go very deep in their documentation/code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't touch the django contributed `User` model (from the authentication framework). This will break upgrades and you do not know what other consequences it might have.

There are two basic ways to do this:

1. If you just need to store additional information about a user, but don't need to change how the authentication/authorization mechanism works, create a model and add a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) to the `User` model. In this model, store any other miscellaneous information.
2. If you want to change how authentication works you can [create your own `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) and have django use that (1.5+ only).

Comment: This isn't correct if you're starting a new app in 1.5. New best practice if you just need to add additional fields is to inherit from AbstractUser.

Comment: No, you only inherit from AbstractUserModel when you are creating a User model _replacement_; and you shouldn't do that if you just want to add a field. You should create your own User model replacement if you are implementing some fundamental change in how the authentication/authorization process will work for your application.

Comment: I'm not talking about AbstractBaseUser, which is creating a replacement.  I'm talking about AbstractUser.  From the docs: "If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to add some additional profile information, you can simply subclass django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile fields. This class provides the full implementation of the default User as an abstract model."

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user (link wouldn't fit in previous comment character limit)

Comment: Interesting, what if I were using a third party app. How should I be using a third party app that provides a BaseUser class that is meant to be subclassed with additional model logic.

Comment: Interesting.  Could you give an example of a third-party app that would require that?  It sounds like in that case you'd be using their model instead of Django's built-in user anyway, so you'd have to reference the app's documentation.