# Django add two fields to user profile

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to add two additional profile fields and have the native authentication work like normal.

I am trying to fallow the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user/)
and the SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880461/django-1-5-user-model-relationship/)

In my settings file

```
#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

in my users.user model

```
#users/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='Blue')
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='Blue')
    print "user.user"
```

i have created 3 superusers non can log into admin. i have tried syncing the DB after adding a user. i have tried restating the dev server between adding a user.

the only time i see the output of print "user.user" is when i run the createsuperuser command.

i think i cant log in because the user is not really being created. it runs my User class and then skips actually creating the user. but i am kinda new to this so i could be way off and way out of my league.

why cant i log in and how do i add the two fields?

Comment: How exactly are you creating the users?

Comment: Have you messed around in the shell at all? (`./manage.py shell`). Try to confirm your suspicions, `from users.models import User\ u = User.objects.all()\ u[0].foo`

Comment: @DanielRoseman: manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: @Johndt6 that command gives a syntax error. I tried adding "" but no go. i dont now what else to try to make this work.

Comment: I didn't mean to copy and paste exactly that- I was separating commands by `\`. So import your user, than run a query and see if any User objects exist, then, if they do, see if they have attributes of your modified user.

Comment: @Johndt6  i tried a little of that before. but this time i got it to work. so i was wrong it appears it is creating the users and they do have a field named foo with a default value of blue.  so why cant i log in with any of these users?  Grrr

Comment: u[0].is_staff and u[0].is_active come back as True

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the warning in Django's documentation?

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL has a big effect on your database structure. It changes the tables that are available, and it will affect the construction of foreign keys and many-to-many relationships. If you intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before running manage.py syncdb for the first time.
>
> If you have an existing project and you want to migrate to using a custom User model, you may need to look into using a migration tool like South to ease the transition.

Given this warning, are you working on a fresh database, or are you migrating using South? If you have an existing database and made these changes, then simply running syncdb will most likely no be sufficient.

If this is a development server without any important data, I would recreate your database, and then run `./manage.py syncdb`. If you are using a SQLite database, then you can simply copy it to somewhere else (if you would like to keep the data), and run syncdb again to create a new database.

[Here is the relevant documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

It would also be helpful to know exactly what error you are receiving. Do you attempt to login and admin tells you that your user/pass combination is not correct, or is there an actual error thrown? Your question doesn't quite make this clear.